# airflow big dag_pickle table

Tags: python, pickle, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow, data-pipeline

I set up a test installation of airflow a while ago with one test DAG which is in paused state.

Now, after this system ran for some weeks without actually doing much (beside some test runs), I wanted to dump the database and realized, it is huge.

This is due to the dag_pickle table, apprently airflow creates a pickle object and persits that in the database *every second*.

However, none of these pickle rows in the database are related to the dag, the **pickle_id** field in the dag row is empty:

```
mysql> select * from dag;
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+
| dag_id           | is_paused | is_subdag | is_active | last_scheduler_run         | last_pickled | last_expired               | scheduler_lock | pickle_id | fileloc                               | owners  |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+
| test_dag         |         1 |         0 |         1 | 2017-05-10 11:13:57.987710 | NULL         | 2017-05-10 09:40:19.449429 |           NULL |      NULL | /opt/airflow/dags/test_dag.py         | airflow |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Checking the dag_pickle table we see that every second, one row is created:

```
mysql> select max(created_dttm), count(*), now() from dag_pickle;
+----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
| max(created_dttm)          | count(*) | now()               |
+----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2017-05-10 11:20:26.000000 |  1893572 | 2017-05-10 11:20:26 | 
+----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (13.71 sec)

mysql> select max(created_dttm), count(*), now() from dag_pickle;
+----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
| max(created_dttm)          | count(*) | now()               |
----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2017-05-10 11:20:40.000000 |  1893586 | 2017-05-10 11:20:41 |
+----------------------------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (12.55 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1893586-1893572 as delta, TIMEDIFF('2017-05-10 11:20:41','2017-05-10 11:20:26') as time_delta;
+-------+------------+
| delta | time_delta |
+-------+------------+
|    14 | 00:00:15   |
+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(As you can see, this table is so big that it becomes an operational burden, it is by now 7.5 GB of size)

My questions now are:

1. Are all these pickle rows used for anything, or can I savely delete them? (I assume the latter, because there is no reference from a dag) Is there some cleanup procedure to remove unused stuff from the database?
2. Is this an error in my configuration or in airflow? Can I configure airflow such that these pickle object are only created when and if they are actually needed?
3. What effect does the **donot_pickle** configuration option have exactly, can I still run the DAG from a worker on another machine with the CeleryExecutor if donot_pickle is set to **True**?

Thanks!

Comment: any chance you can share your airflow.cfg + any AIRFLOW envvars?  I am looking into something related.

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution ?

Comment: No, I never figured that out and I do not work at this project any more. As far as I remember, I simply set donot_pickle to true and was done with it. I still could run DAGs on other machines (as for question 3).